# How to hide drop down list when clicked outside in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Programmaticaly how can we close or hide drop down list when clicked outside in iphone?

```
-(void)RecommendDropDownSelect
{
dropDown=[[DropDownView alloc]initWithArrayData:arr_RecommendName  cellHeight:30 heightTableView:100 paddingTop:-100 paddingLeft:10 paddingRight:20 refView:txt_Recommend animation:BLENDIN openAnimationDuration:0.5 closeAnimationDuration:0.5];
dropDown.delegate=self;
[scr_View addSubview:dropDown.view];
[dropDown openAnimation];


btn_RecommendDropDown.enabled=NO;
}

-(void)dropDownCellSelected:(NSInteger)returnIndex
{
btn_RecommendDropDown.enabled=YES;
txt_Recommend.text=[arr_RecommendName objectAtIndex:returnIndex];

}
```

Comment: iPhone me drop down kab se aa gaya?

Comment: use the tap gesture to hide the drop down list

Comment: you can use (void)touchesBegan: for your view or add a tap gesture to your view and on tap hide/remove dropDown view. Is  it such a big deal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides subclassing `UIView` and override `touchesBegan`, using `UITapGestureRecognizer` seems to be easier if you are using `UIViewController`

First, setup a tap gesture for your view:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideDropDown)];
[gestureRecognizer setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

then implement the method for hiding the dropdown:

```
- (void)hideDropDown
{
    if ((dropDown != nil) && (dropDown.view != nil))
    {
        [drdropDown.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Owen for ur help but need one more help if i access some value from drop down list in my textfield i have to press on that value for long to get that value in textfield.So how can i access it easily with just one click on it?

Comment: could you post the source code for your dropdown? and, please make it another stackoverflow question so more people can help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
         UITouch *touch = [touches  anyObject];
           if (touch.view==self.view) {
             [dropDown removeFromSuperView];
          }
      }
```

or

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches  anyObject];
      if (touch.view==self.view) {
           dropDown.alpha=0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would go for the second one, hiding the menu with alpha. Remember removing and adding views uses more memory, you are actually allocating memory once the view is created and removing it each time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
   if(dropDown)
   {
      [drdropDown.view removeFromSuperView];
   }
}
```